# Pro C code to connect to Database giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, unix

I have the below code in my .pc file which is called by almost 10 processes but for one process its not working as showing "Core dump/Segmentation Fault" .
This is the code which is called by every process as the first step to connect to Database.
Please suggest where is the problem in the below code -:

```
void DatabaseLogon (void)
{
   EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
      char *pchORALOG="";
   EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

   EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO SQLError();

   /* Save text of current SQL statement in the ORACA if an error occurs. */

   oraca.orastxtf = ORASTFERR;

   /* try to get the oracle login user/pass at the process level */
        if ( (pchORALOG=getenv("oralog")) == NULL )
        {
         printf("Error:Cannot Logon to database!\n");
         SQLError();
        }
      else
        {
         EXEC SQL CONNECT :pchORALOG;
        }
} /* End Of DatabaseLogon */
```

Thanks
Arpita

Comment: If your getting a core dump then looking at the dump in you debugger might well give you a clue.  Also what makes you think that this is the piece of code that's causing the problem?

Comment: I just did pstack core and I saw its stuck at Databaselogon() and there since there were no debug symbols found in core dump so could not debug further... And as far as Pro C concerned its Pro *C !!!

Comment: Can you paste us the debug info of the core file ?

Comment: Add printf calls between each line so you can see where it segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

My ProC connect statement looks like this:
EXEC SQL CONNECT :user IDENTIFIED BY :passwd USING :database;

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to modify a read only location here.

```
pchORALOG=getenv("oralog")
```

below statement is the problem:

```
char *pchORALOG="";
```

change it to:

```
char *pchORALOG;
```

Comment: You are mistaken.  getenv returns a const char *, pointing to the value of the environment variable.  In the example code this replaces the pointer to the "" string constant.  This is fine.